# program to input 8 numbers from user and display all the unique no's

Tags: numbers, unique, display

output doesn't return unique list with this code. It simply return the list with random order

unique=[]

for i in range(9):
a=input("enter no.")
unique.append(a)
print(unique)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check if the element already exists or not. The solution would be

```
unique=[]
for i in range(9): 
   a=input("enter no.")
   if a not in unique # add this line
      unique.append(a)
print(unique)
```